# excel Vba to save the same file according to list of names

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel file (office 365) "File 1" in folder C:\Users\user\Desktop\test and i need to save the exact same file in the same folder but with different file names. I have a list of all the names that i need to save my files in column  P of "File 1" starting from cell P1 = 101 and ending in cell P 209= 309. So for example when i run the macro i will get in this folder 209 files exactly like "File 1" but thefile name will be 101 to 309.

can anyone please help?

Comment: Do the file names in P:P column contain the file extension? If yes, it is a matter of .xlsx, or .xlsm? When you say 'file' do you mean workbook? Is the workbook keeping the necessary code the one to be copied with those different names? Besides all that, did you try anything by your own?

Comment: all the files contain the extension .xlsx. By file i mean workbook and it won't keep the code. Unfortunatelly i have little experience and mostly by using the macro recorder.

Comment: How do you know the full name of the workbook to be copied? Would you like to select it in a browse window? Do you like using it as a string: "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\myWorbook.xlsx"?

Comment: You just have to create a `For` loop and use `.SaveAs()`

Comment: @Dean: I think there is no need to even open it...

Comment: @FaneDuru Would be easy to write a python script to do that tbh..

Comment: @Dean: If he does not know VBA, do you think he knows working in python? I have some doubts... It is possible in VBA.

Comment: @FaneDuru the best solution would be to use it as a string "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\myWorbook.xlsx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It does not need to open the workbook and it should be very fast. Clearly faster than using `SaveAs`:

```
Sub testCopyWorkbookDifferentNames()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, El, oFSO As Object
  Dim origName As String, foldPath As String, newFold As String
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  origName = "myWorbook.xlsx"
  foldPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\"
  newFold = foldPath & "NewFold"
  Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  
  If Dir(newFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir newFold
  lastR = sh.Range("P" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in P:P
  arr = sh.Range("P1:P" & lastR).Value
  For Each El In arr
    oFSO.CopyFile foldPath & origName, newFold & "\" & El, True 'True to overwrite
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename the files using a range of names in the same workbook, then you can store the below code in that workbook. Adjust the parameters to what you need them to be.

Given the below range:

[image]

And running this code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub saveAs()
    
    Dim nameRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set nameRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")
    
    For Each cell In nameRng
        'defaults to location of where this file is stored
        ThisWorkbook.saveAs cell.Text, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Next cell
    
    
End Sub
```

You will get:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @dean it is working great!